# How to check duplicate posting in different date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've found there are duplicate dummy event (card out) being captured on different date in my DB. The full event should be captured in sequence (card in, pin verification, input withdraw amount, cash out, card out). what query i can use to find out all impacted ATM that having this kind of scenarios (not full event being captured after order by date),how to find out the date that ATM capturing dummy card out event for each atm? i need to figure out those date that machine having card out event in continuous row (doesn't contain other event in between each of card out event)

```
select date, atm, event
from table 
where atm = a 
order by date desc

DATE              ATM   Event
24/10/2017 20:59    a   Card out
22/10/2017 10:12    a   Card out
20/10/2017 17:20    a   Card out
17/10/2017 20:59    a   Card out
17/09/2017 17:22    a   Card out
17/09/2017 17:22    a   Cash out
17/09/2017 17:21    a   input withdraw amount
17/09/2017 17:20    a   PIN verification
17/09/2017 17:20    a   Card in
16/09/2017 17:22    a   Cash out
16/09/2017 17:21    a   input withdraw amount
16/09/2017 17:20    a   PIN verification
16/09/2017 17:20    a   Card in
```

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Are you sure that's the result of the query? The data is not even sorted.

Comment: the full event should be card in, pin verification, input withdraw amount, cash out, card out. but some reason to machine and keep sending card out event on different date so i need to figure out how many atm are having this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, are you looking for something like that; (finding duplicate ATM and Event fields)

```
select ATM,Event from Table group by ATM,Event having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: nope, i need to find out those dummy data (card out event) that not consider as full event, the full event should be captured like card in, pin verification, input withdraw amount, cash out, card out.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (event = 'Card out' OR event = 'Card in') AND atm IN
(
    SELECT t1.atm FROM
    (
        SELECT atm, COUNT(*) as count
        FROM `table`
        WHERE event = 'Card out'
        GROUP BY ATM
    ) as t1
    FULL JOIN
    (
        SELECT atm, COUNT(*) as count
        FROM `table`
        WHERE event = 'Card in'
        GROUP BY ATM
    ) as t2
    ON t1.ATM = t2.ATM
    WHERE t1.COUNT > t2.COUNT
)
ORDER BY date
ORDER BY atm
```

What this query does is it first count how many card out event are there for each ATM, then count how many card in event for each atm and list out all atm which have card out event more than card in event. Then use the list of atm with defects to list out all the corresponding card in and card out event.

The sort order will put the list in order of atm and within each atm, it will be sorted by date. You can then use the list to check where are the duplicated card out event by eliminating every card out event with a card in event before. Currently I have no idea how to do this in SQL but i can do this rather easily in other programming language.

Comment: how to find out the date that ATM capturing dummy card out event for each atm? i need to figure out those date that machine having card out event in continues row (doesn't contain other event in between each of card out event)

Comment: Modified my answer to get the list of event of card in and card out. After you get the list, all you need to do is remove all card out event without card in event before then all you left with are the duplicated card out event (does not have a card in pair)